# Codeigniter Form Validation is_unique on Updation

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I am working on admin panel for website related to domains and I have different scenarios.
How can I check uniqueness of my domain name when updating the data.Like When I add the data it's working OK.

> $this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name','Domain
>   Name','required|is_unique[domains.domain_name]',array('is_unique' =>
>   'This %s already exists.'));

But when I going for updating the record I am confused how can it be possible.

If admin clicks on edit the domain data and he don't want to change the domain name but he wants to update any other field when clicks on update button It shows error of that This domain name already exists.

> > My question is that is it possible when admin is updating the form if he wants to update the form without changing the domain name ,it should not show error of unique..... But If he change the domain name then it should check the uniqueness.
> >     I have different forms for adding and updating the domains data.

How can I Fix this problem. can anyone help????

Comment: we can do this using ajax....try with ajax.....

Comment: accept the answer..

Answer (score 3):

When you edit the form then store the actual value in hidden field ,when you click to update the field ,check with hidden field value and text field value ,if they are same then do not apply the condition like this

```
if($this->input->post("actual_value")==$this->input->post("updated_textfield_value")){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name','Domain Name','required');
}else{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name','Domain Name','required|is_unique[domains.domain_name]',array('is_unique' => 'This %s already exists.'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Rajat It helps

Answer (score 1):

This solution allow you to declear your column name like columnID Create a custom validation class in application\libraries\MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    public function edit_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field, $columnIdName, $id);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str, $columnIdName .'!=' => $id))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }
}
```

Add this to system\language\english\form_validation_lang.php

```
$lang['form_validation_edit_unique']= 'The supplied value is already taken.';
```

To use in your controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]|edit_unique[mytable.mycolumn.columnID.'.$id.']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this issue myself. My solution is to extend the Form Validation Library and slightly modify the original is_unique method by adding another 'where' clause to exclude self.

In controller:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name', 'Domain Name', 'update_is_unique[domains.domain_name.'.$id.']', 
    array('update_is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'));
```

In libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }    

    public function update_is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field, $id);
        return $this->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str, 'id !=' => $id))->num_rows() === 0;
    }
}
```